# Has many through association with boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models. `Organizer`, `Organization`, `Connection`.

```
# Schema Information
#
# Table name: connections
#
# organizer_id       :integer
# organization_id    :integer
# admin              :boolean      default(false)

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizer
  belongs_to :organization
end

-----------

# Schema Information
#
# Table name: organizations
#
# name               :string

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :connections
  has_many :organizers, through: :connections
end

-----------

# Schema Information
#
# Table name: organizers
#
# name               :string
# ...

class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :connections
  has_many :organizations, through: :connections
end
```

With this association, I can easily find what organization an organizer has, and vise versa. The part I am overcomplicating, is how to tell which organization an organizer is **admin** to. And I'm basing this off the `admin` boolean on the `Connection` table.

So far, I was able to find the **admins** of an organization with this query:

```
Organization.find(...).connections.where(admin: true)
```

From there, I figured I would check if this association `includes?` a specific organizer, but it gives me false when it should be true.

```
Organization.find(...).connections.where(admin: true).include?(Organizer.find(...))
```

But I'm looking for an way to check if a specific `organizer` is the **admin** of a specific `organization`. Perhaps the way I set up the associations is incorrect. It's been baffling me today. Any advice on this would really be appreciated.

*Disclaimer:*
There can be multiple **admins** per organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're searching for organizers amongst a collection of connections which is what's causing the statement to return false. You need to first map the connections to the organizers  they belong to like so:

```
Organization.find(...).connections.where(admin: true).map(&:organizer).include?(Organizer.find(...))
```